# Does gsl::not_null hurt performance?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

[C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines) recommends a `gsl::not_null` type. As stated in [I.12: Declare a pointer that must not be null as `not_null`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#-i12-declare-a-pointer-that-must-not-be-null-as-not_null):

> To help avoid dereferencing nullptr errors. To improve performance by
> avoiding redundant checks for nullptr.
>
> ...
>
> By stating the intent in
> source, implementers and tools can provide better diagnostics, such as
> finding some classes of errors through static analysis, and perform
> optimizations, such as removing branches and null tests.

(If interested, this is Microsoft's implementation of `gsl::not_null`: [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/pointers))

The guideline doc says it helps performance by "removing branches and null tests". But, it also adds an overhead because methods `operator->()` and `operator*()` are to be called if I want to access the underlying pointer (that is not counting the Microsoft implementation's overhead of runtime checks in these methods).

Given that method inlining is not guaranteed, how did the doc conclude the net performance gain is positive?

Comment: "Given that method inlining is not guaranteed, how did the doc conclude the net performance gain is positive?" benchmarking

Comment: While you aren't guaranteed a function call will be inlined, most/all compilers will inline wrapper code like this since it knows it's supposed to be a "zero cost" abstraction.

Comment: _Given that method inlining is not guaranteed_ ... if you're concerned about quality-of-implementation issues like this, you need to pick an implementation and actually test. Who knows, maybe you have a uniquely terrible implementation - we certainly can't tell you.

Comment: Ok, so indeed the doc made an assumption that is not theoretically guaranteed to be true. I thought there's some reasoning behind the writing.

Comment: @t.niese Only if you define `GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION`.

Comment: "the doc made an assumption" or measured on common platforms

Comment: I now had time to check the code. @eerorika is right, there are not exceptions involved in the default settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, it also adds an overhead because methods operator->() and operator*()

Except, those functions are defined inline and are extremely small, thereby optimiser will (very likely) expand them inline, which would remove that potential overhead entirely.

> how did the doc conclude the net performance gain is positive?

As you quoted, the document doesn't even acknowledge associated overhead, so such conclusion is trivial.

If you mean how did the authors of the document come to such conclusion, only those authors know. It may range from "they measured its effects" to "they made an assumption".